# Concatenating multiple data frame and Ordering the row in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge multiple data frames. Here is the example code for data frames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [0, 5, 9],
    [0.3434, 4, 61],
    [10.22, 24, 9]]),
    columns=['time', 'attr11', 'attr12'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [0, 5, 19],
    [0.3, 14, 16],
    [9.99, 4, 9]]),
    columns=['time', 'attr21', 'attr22'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [0, 15, 49],
    [6.66, 4, 36],
    [9.66, 14, 9]]),
    columns=['time', 'attr31', 'attr32'])
```

Now if I do, Concatenating

```
con = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], ignore_index=True, sort=True)
sorted_data = con.sort_values(by="time")
```

I get the (almost ) output what I am looking for, But There is an extra three row for `0`.

Here Is the output I am getting

```
attr11  attr12  attr21  attr22  attr31  attr32  time
0   5.0 9.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.0000
3   NaN NaN 5.0 19.0    NaN NaN 0.0000
6   NaN NaN NaN NaN 15.0    49.0    0.0000
4   NaN NaN 14.0    16.0    NaN NaN 0.3000
1   4.0 61.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.3434
7   NaN NaN NaN NaN 4.0 36.0    6.6600
8   NaN NaN NaN NaN 14.0    9.0 9.6600
5   NaN NaN 4.0 9.0 NaN NaN 9.9900
2   24.0    9.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN 10.2200
```

The zero time row should Have one row , not three, Therefore there will be no `NaN` in Zero time row.

this should the first row look like

```
0  5.0  9.0 5.0 19.0 15.0 49
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: what did you get ?

Comment: with the same code ?

Comment: so sorry, updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need create index by `time` column first and then [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) by columns with `axis=1`, indices are sorted by default:

```
con = pd.concat([df1.set_index('time'),
                 df2.set_index('time'),
                 df3.set_index('time')], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Or if working with list of `DataFrames`:

```
dfs = [x.set_index('time') for x in [df1, df2, df3]]
con = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index()
```

---

```
print (con)
      time  attr11  attr12  attr21  attr22  attr31  attr32
0   0.0000     5.0     9.0     5.0    19.0    15.0    49.0
1   0.3434     4.0    61.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   6.3300     NaN     NaN    14.0    16.0     NaN     NaN
3   6.6600     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     4.0    36.0
4   9.6600     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN    14.0     9.0
5   9.9900     NaN     NaN     4.0     9.0     NaN     NaN
6  10.2200    24.0     9.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
aggregation_functions = {'attr11':'sum','attr12':'sum','attr21':'sum','attr22':'sum','attr31':'sum','attr32':'sum'}
con_new = con.groupby(con['time']).aggregate(aggregation_functions)
con_new
```